# htaccess decode url in three values

Tags: .htaccess

Good afternoon,

I'm trying to edit my .htaccess in order to decode an url in 3 values.

An example of url is: example.com/VALUEa/article-VALUEb&VALUEc

The code I have tried is the following but it doesn't work.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/article-([^/]+)&([^/]+) request.php?VALUEa=$1&VALUEb=$2&VALUEc=$3 [L]
```

Do you have some tips to correct it?

#EDIT 1 AND 2

I tried to edit the code following the suggestion, but stil does not work.
The new full code I have inserted is the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^  https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml sitemap.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^/?$ index.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^images/favicons/([^/]+)/?$ images/favicons/$1 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^images/([^/]+)/?$ images/$1 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/article-([^/]+)&([^/]+)/?$ request.php?VALUEa=$1&VALUEb=$2&VALUEc=$3 [NC,L]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples, could you please try following Rules. Please do clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^  https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml sitemap.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^images/favicons/([^/]+)/?$ images/favicons/$1 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^images/([^/]+)/?$ images/$1 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/article-([^/]+)&([^/]+)/?$ request.php?VALUEa=$1&VALUEb=$2&VALUEc=$3 [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,NC,L]
```

Comment: Nice answer. Ravinder . ++ for using the NE flag.